# Using struct.pack with strings

Tags: python, struct

I'm trying to use the struct.pack so I can write a string into a file. When I do, I get the following error:

```
File "----", line 166, in main
struct.pack('>256s', *master_header)
struct.error: pack expected 1 items for packing (got 256)
```

Now, reading from [here](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html) I seem to be using it right. I specify that I'm getting 256 bytes/characters in my string.

I'm using version 3.3.3.

Comment: Why do you add the `*`?

Comment: "so I can write a string into a file" - as in, you have a string, and you want to write it to a file, or you have something else, and you want to make it a string so you can write it to a file?

Comment: I have a 256 byte string I want to pack into a binary string using struct.pack.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html) says:

> For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the size of
>   the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters;
>   for example, '10s' means a single 10-byte string, while '10c' means 10
>   characters.

So, `>256s` expects a single string 256 bytes long. If `master_header` already is such a string, just pass it to `struct.pack` without the `*`.

Using the `*` at the call site causes the string itself to be unpacked into its constituent characters, strings being iterable. As a result, `struct.pack` receives its 256 individual characters as arguments, causing the observed error.

Comment: master_header is a single string that's 256 bytes long.

Comment: @zdc000 In that case, just lose the `*`.